# Css performance: better to address child elements with tag name or classes?

Tags: css, performance, sass

I am using scss. I would like to know which method have best performances between addressing the child elements with their tag name or instancing new classes, and also which method is considered best practice:

```css
.product{
  &__image{}
  &__header{}
}

.product{
  img{}
  h5{}
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
         <img class="product__image" src="" alt="">
         <h5 class="product__header"> </h5>
  </div>
```

Comment: for the best practice method I suggest to use classes organized with BEM in order to have a style not markup-dependant.

Comment: Assuming that selectors are evalutated right to left simple class selector seems more performant. `.product img` would first match every `img` and then css engine have to traverse up to the very root of DOM tree to check if any parent has class `product`. But this is from theoretical point of view. There might be various optimizations implemented by each engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your HTML. Do you really need a class for every element?

My main rule of thumb is: if I need to style **multiple items** in a similar way *and* they are **semantically or structurally related**, add a class. In such a case, you would then simply use the class in your CSS to target all the elements.

```
.profile-pictures {max-width: 67%;}
```

However, if the elements are not related in any way or you are only targeting a single element, just use the tagname.

```
header h1, figcaption {text-align: center;}
```

The important part here is *semantics*. HTML5 is all about the linked web. Not only the relations between web pages, but also the clear structure of a single web page. In my opinion, semantically clear tags are part of that. A fellow developer should be able to *read* your code and get a feeling about the structure and make-up without actually seeing the result in a browser.

This also means that I am not at all a fan of classes such as `product__image`, because it is derived from a class and a tag. So how does it differ from `.product img`? Leaving specificity aside, it doesn't - but it does involve a lot of overhead HTML that you actually don't need. In my humble opinion, these kind of classes bloat your HTML into an unreadable, redundant mess.

To conclude and to summarise: stick to CSS selectors and class names where they make sense semantically. Group elements with classes where it is semantically or structurally an obvious choice. Do not bloat your HTML with classes for every element. Remember the 2005 cliché, *less is more*.